# Correct python re regex

Tags: python, regex

I tried to make regex to validate phone number in format +38(0XX)XXX-XX-XX or 0XX-XXX-XX-XX. My regex is: `'^(\+38)*(\(*0\d{2}\)*)[-|\s](\d{3})[-|\s]((\d{2})-|\s)+$'`. And it's not matched any way. I reread `re` syntax a couple of times, can't get how to make it right.

Comment: It seems you meant `+38(0XX)-XXX-XX-XX` by looking at your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Making the regex to match strictly as per the comments.

This regex should work according to your requirements

```
^((\+38)?\(0\d{2}\)|0\d{2})[-\s]\d{3}([-\s]\d{2}){2}$
```

This matches `+38(022)-333-33-44`, `(022)-333-33-44` and `022-333-33-44`

Comment: this will also match 022-333-33-44-77-33-44-23-56 and 045 333 44-37 :)

Comment: @scriptmonster OP had `+` in the end, I didn't want to change his regex completely. If needed he can replace `+` in the end with `{2}` or `{3}` as required. Also looks like OP's regex had both `-` and `\s` as possible delimiters.

Comment: Well but it will match with +38(022-333-33-44, +38022)-333-33-44 and +38022-333-33-44. 
I don't think that he's aware of that.

Comment: @scriptmonster I updated the regex to be more strict. Hope you won't rip it off any more ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is an another option. It looks for exact formats that you mentioned.

```
'^(\+38\(0\d{2}\)\d{3}(-\d{2}){2})|(0\d{2}-\d{3}(-\d{2}){2})$'
```